# Creating new variable that counts a certain string in other variable in r

Tags: r, csv

I want to create a new variable called `Chatid` that gets +1 for each time `Chat ID: ^^^^^^` appears in the Lead variable.

This is how the .csv looks like now

```
Lead,Event,Role,Data
Chat ID: ^^^^^^,,,
No Value,x,Lead,No Value
No Value,x,End-user,No Value
Man,Lead x,Lead,No Value
Man,x,Lead,No Value
Man,x,Lead,Hello
Man,x,Lead,No Value
No Value,x,End-user,Hello to you too
Man,x,Lead,how are you?
Chat ID: ^^^^^^,,,
No Value,x,Lead,No Value
No Value,x,End-user,No Value
Man,x,Lead,No Value
Man,x,Lead,Hello, how are you?
Man,x,Lead,No Value
Man,x,Lead,No Value
Man,x,Lead,Can i help you?
No Value,x,End-user,Goodmorning!
```

How it should look like after write.csv

```
Chatid, Lead,Event,Role,Data
1,Chat ID: ^^^^^^,,,
1,No Value,x,Lead,No Value
1,No Value,x,End-user,No Value
1,Man,Lead x,Lead,No Value
1,Man,x,Lead,No Value
1,Man,x,Lead,Hello
1,Man,x,Lead,No Value
1,No Value,x,End-user,Hello to you too
1,Man,x,Lead,how are you?
2,Chat ID: ^^^^^^,,,
2,No Value,x,Lead,No Value
2,No Value,x,End-user,No Value
2,Man,x,Lead,No Value
2,Man,x,Lead,Hello, how are you?
2,Man,x,Lead,No Value
2,Man,x,Lead,No Value
2,Man,x,Lead,Can i help you?
2,No Value,x,End-user,Goodmorning!
```

This way I want to make it possible to analyse each separate chat (if this is the best way to separate the different chats).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `grepl` to find the occurrences of the string of interest, and then cumsum over the output. For a `data.frame` called `df`:

```
df <- cbind(
        Chatid = cumsum(grepl("Chat ID", df$lead)), 
        df
      )
```

Comment: or simplier `df$chatid <-  cumsum(grepl("Chat ID", df$Lead))`

Comment: @GGamba yes - I started with that - but changed so the columns were in the order the OP wanted